# Symfony doctrine:generate-module custom theme: cannot find templates for i18n embedded field

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, crud

I generated a custom theme by copying

```
plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/default"
```

into

```
plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/data/generator/sfDoctrineModule/mytheme1"
```

I changed the templates to match my needs (no tables, custom errors display and so on).

```
./symfony doctrine:generate-module --theme=mytheme1 frontend user User
```

works as I expected however if I add

```
$this->embedI18n(array('en','fr'));
```

to the **form** class the generator renders the I18n embedded form with  and .

Where do this come from? How can I customize it? where are the template files for i18n embedded forms located?

Thanks a lot,
Massimo

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it's not the best idea to overload a theme in the plugin itself. Plugin's shouldn't be touched to allow future updates. You can easily overload the theme in your application.

Secondly something seems to be missing in your post: "to the form class the generator renders the I18n embedded form with and ."

Maybe missing translation indicators are shown?

Comment: yes there's domething missing! it uses table cells and table rows even if I have stripped them away from my custom template. I cannot figure out where do they come from

Comment: After I have fix all theese stuff I will move my theme inside my project. Thanks for your advices however!

Comment: Is it a "T" letter between "[" and "]" ? If it is than it's just a missing translation indicator (configured and enabled in factories.yml).

Comment: No, it's a template layout problem. The form is rendered in the right way, I mean I can see all the fields. When you specify $this->embedI18n(array('it','fr'); It creates a block of code for each language. The problem is that this block of code comes from an unknown template. I need to find and customize that template. can you help me to find it?

Comment: Second parameter for embedI18n() method is an html decorator. You can use it to change the html for embedded form.

Answer (score 1):

The template is defined in the formatter of the widgetSchema of your i18n form. By default, it is set to sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterTable which contains the definition of what you are looking for :

```
class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterTable extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{
  protected
    $rowFormat       = "<tr>\n  <th>%label%</th>\n  <td>%error%%field%%help%%hidden_fields%</td>\n</tr>\n",
    $errorRowFormat  = "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">\n%errors%</td></tr>\n",
    $helpFormat      = '<br />%help%',
    $decoratorFormat = "<table>\n  %content%</table>";
}
```

You can change this by editing your i18n form class initialization. For example, if you want to display the fields in a list :

```
public function setup()
{
    parent::setup();

    $formatter = new sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterList($this->getWidgetSchema());

    $this->getWidgetSchema()->addFormFormatter('list', $formatter);
    $this->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatterName('list');
}
```

You can also define your own formatter inheriting from sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter to match your layout preferences.